# Why can't I set two different states from the same response object?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3

I'm getting an S3 signed URL response back to my client from my NodeJS server which handles communication with S3. I need the signed URL to upload images directly to S3 from my front end, and I need the image URL to display it from the S3 bucket. However I can't seem to set two different states with the same response object without getting a 403(Forbidden) error. I can set one state just fine and use it, but as soon as I try and set two using the same response object, it doesn't like it.
[403Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWe4y.png)

```
 useEffect(() => {
async function getURL() { try {
    await axios.get("imageRouter/S3Url").then((response) => {
      setImageUrl(response.data.url.split("?")[0]);
      setSignedUrl(response.data.url);
    });} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }}

getURL();}, 
[selectedFile]);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `selectedFile` is not a dependency of `useEffect`, the two dependencies are: `setImageUrl` and `setSignedUrl` and you should cache them so they won't change every time the state changes (using `React.memo`).
2. You should check the signed URL that is returned, by default the expiration is 15 minutes IIRC, so if you generate it once and use it multiple times you should make sure that it's not expired and if so - regenerate it. This can be checked by looking at the `Expires` parameter which shows up as a query param on the signed-url. We can use: https://www.epochconverter.com/ to translate it to a timestamp in a more readable format